# Is \\*.zip skipping other files with zip in the name?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline that consumes the build artifact and deploys it on the app service. The artifact has the following file `jszip.min.js` yet when the deployment occurs, it appears the file gets deleted in the app service, so I have to reupload it manually after the deployment which is frustrating.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

File gone after new deployment:

[image: 3]

I've tried including it explicitly in the skipObject arguments:

```
....0.png|jszip.min.js|\\*.zip
```

but that didn't include it in the next deployment from the artifact and thus the file was still missing following the new deployment.

A reason considered is because in the additional arguments of the **Azure App Service Deploy** task, I have `skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="...\\*.zip`. However, I doubt that is the reason because the filename in question is `jszip` **not** `js.zip`, so there should be no reason it would possibly match that to .zip.

So what is the issue and how do I make sure the `jszip.min.js` makes it to the app service upon deployment like other files?

**Azure App Service Deploy YAML**

```
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: app-dev'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure Dev Service Connection'
    WebAppName: 'app-dev'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/Release'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    AdditionalArguments: '-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="Web.Dev.config|Web.Test.config|Web.Beta.config|Web.Prod.config|android-icon-144x144.png|android-icon-192x192.png|android-icon-36x36.png|android-icon-48x48.png|android-icon-72x72.png|android-icon-96x96.png|apple-touch-icon-114x114.png|apple-touch-icon-120x120.png|apple-touch-icon-144x144.png|apple-touch-icon-152x152.png|apple-touch-icon-180x180.png|apple-touch-icon-57x57.png|apple-touch-icon-60x60.png|apple-touch-icon-72x72.png|apple-touch-icon-76x76.png|apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png|apple-touch-icon.png|favicon-16x16.png|favicon-32x32.png|favicon-96x96.png|apple-icon.png|ms-icon-144x144.png|ms-icon-150x150.png|ms-icon-310x310.png|ms-icon-70x70.png|\\*.zip" -retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000'
    enableXmlTransform: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The situation is expected. And this situation is caused by how you design.

I can reproduce your situation and I can solve the issue.

Use the below YAML:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'xxx'
    packageForLinux: 'xxx'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    AdditionalArguments: '-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="Web.Dev.config|Web.Test.config|Web.Beta.config|Web.Prod.config|android-icon-144x144.png|android-icon-192x192.png|android-icon-36x36.png|android-icon-48x48.png|android-icon-72x72.png|android-icon-96x96.png|apple-touch-icon-114x114.png|apple-touch-icon-120x120.png|apple-touch-icon-144x144.png|apple-touch-icon-152x152.png|apple-touch-icon-180x180.png|apple-touch-icon-57x57.png|apple-touch-icon-60x60.png|apple-touch-icon-72x72.png|apple-touch-icon-76x76.png|apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png|apple-touch-icon.png|favicon-16x16.png|favicon-32x32.png|favicon-96x96.png|apple-icon.png|ms-icon-144x144.png|ms-icon-150x150.png|ms-icon-310x310.png|ms-icon-70x70.png|\\*.zip" -retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000'
```

Comment: Wait what is different exactly

Comment: @Cataster Remove jszip.min.js

Comment: `jszip.min.js` is removed from the skip object but I didnt have it initially anyways. I only added it after the file was not deployed from the artifact because I wanted it to be deployed and thought this might be the solution but it didnt deploy it. So whether I include it in skip object or not, the file in the artifact does not get deployed.

Comment: @Cataster Hi, what will happen if you don't enable custom deployment? Will the file still not been deploy?

Comment: I think that option in the GUI is what i have selected as "Web Deploy" method, so it has to be true.

Comment: Any update about this Bowman?